# React Native Debugging on IPad

Tags: xcode, react-native

I created a simple React Native test project as in the [getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) page.

Everything works fine if, in the iPhone simulator, I show the debug menu (Cmd+d).

If I switch to the **iPad** in the Xcode project (General->Deployment Info->Devices->iPad) and try **to show the debug menu** (Cmd-d or shaking on a real device) I get an error in the **main.m** file at the UiApplicationMain as in the picture.[image]

Error window shows:

[image]

I never got this error before but I recently upgraded to Xcode 8.1. 
My React Native version is 0.36

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems there is an already reported bug about this issue in 0.36
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10485